# Debug Assertion Failed (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID)... Is this solution valid?

Tags: c++, containers

Disclaimer: This is for a homework assignment. We have to create a calculator that uses class objects to hold numbers. We have a class called `Element` which goes in a database and holds a class called `Container` that stores numerical data.

I'm getting the aforementioned error with this piece of code. Container is declared here:

```
bool assign(const char* lhs, const char* rhs) {
    Container value;
    bool isValid = parse(rhs, value);
    if (isValid)
    {
            // Code omitted, but you add it to a database
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calls this:

```
bool parse(const char* input, Container& output)
{
    if (IsANumber(input)) // Outside script that checks if input is a scalar
    {
        output = Container(input);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically, this part of the script (of which I have only posted a small part) reads `expression`, and if it is valid, returns a Container object holding `input`. I get the error above, which is being caused by my destructor:

```
Container::~Container()
{
    delete[] data;
}
```

Where `data` is the pointer that stores `input`. I have to comment the body of the destructor out, or my code doesn't work. I assume the destructor is trying to delete `Container`, but is failing because `data` doesn't actually exist (for reasons I do not understand). I can avoid this problem by doing something like this:

```
bool parse(const char* input, Container& output)
{
    if (IsValid(input))
    {
        Container* temp = new Container(input);
        output = *temp;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This adds `temp` to the heap and avoids deletion issues. But I can't help but feel like this is a memory leak, since temp will never be deleted. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is all the constructor, copy constructor, and destructor code for the Container class:

```
// null constructor
Container::Container()
{
    m_nRow = 0;
    m_nCol = 0;
    data = new double[1];
    *(data) = 0;
}

// scalar constructor
Container::Container(double d)
{
    m_nRow = 1;
    m_nCol = 1;
    data = new double[1];
    *(data) = d;
}

// Copy constructor
Container::Container(const Container& copy)
{
    m_nRow = copy.m_nRow;
    m_nCol = copy.m_nCol;

    data = new double[m_nRow * m_nCol];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_nCol; j++)
        {
            *(m_aData + i * m_nCol + j) = *(copy.m_aData + i * m_nCol + j);
        }
    }
}

Container::~Container()
{
    //delete[] data;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't show the declaration for data, or where it is allocated.   Please show ALL relevant code.

Comment: When you say value = *temp, you mean output = *temp ? Can you post declaration of Container ?

Comment: There is a lot of code... Like 1200+ lines. Also value is supposed to be output. I posted the declaration. It is declared in the function that calls it.

Comment: If you have memory allocation you usually need constructor, assignment and copy constructor as well, or you will copy pointers around and try to delete twice. You could just post the mentioned Container functions.

Comment: Okay, that is up as well. I think the most important thing is probably the copy constructor.

Comment: This is a Rule Of Three violation, you omitted the assignment operator.  The one that the compiler generates *will* trigger this assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
output = Container(input);
```

You didn't declare a copy assignment operator so you get the default one which is member to member assignment. `data` pointer will then be duplicated. Since you are using a local object that goes out of scope at the end of the function, `data` is deleted. Later, when output is destructed, you hit the double delete problem. That is why by introducing a dynamic allocation and not releasing it, it "fixes" the problem.

You should declare a copy assignment operator to also copy data content like in your copy constructor.

You are missing one part of the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). When you need to declare a copy constructor and destructor, you also need a copy assignment operator.

You also have a leak in your copy constructor, you should delete data before re-allocating it.

**EDIT after your comment**

You have a leak in copy constructor because in your other constructor, you allocate an array of 1 element. In the copy constructor, you allocate for the other size without first deleting the previously allocated data array.

For declaring a copy assignment operator you normally return a reference like so:

```
CMatrix& CMatrix::operator=(const CMatrix& mat)
```

but you don't theoretically need to allocate a new object. Although the allocate and swap is a common implementation pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately, the deadline for the assignment has passed, and the late penalty is probably greater than the benefit I'll get from fixing it. That being said, I'm still interested in understanding this.

I tried to implement an assignment operator, but I don't really know how. Is it something like this:
`CMatrix CMatrix::operator=(CMatrix& mat)
{
 CMatrix* temp = new CMatrix(mat);
 return *this;
}`
Also, why is there a leak in my copy constructor? Aren't I creating another copy of `data`?

Comment: @Zapurdead See my edited answer. Also, consider upvoting and/or accepting answer. This is how we thank each other on stackoverflow.